# Vue.js PWA loads twice on startup

Tags: vue.js, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

My PWA shows a behaviour which users say it is very annoying: when loading the application, it loads everything, so that the user can start logging in or using any functionality of the application. But shortly after (typically 3-5 seconds), the app starts again and loads all of the data again.

I read somewhere that this is due to the service worker needs to detect changes on the server, then refreshes to get new content.

But there has not been any update to the application on the server in the meantime, so it is not very clear, why loading the application twice is necessary every time.

Can anyone shade some light on this, if this behaviour can be prevented or worked around and what would be potential downsides?